# caracteres fantasmas añadidos al concadenar 2 cadenas de texto c++

Tags: c++, linux, dev-c++, manejo-de-memoria, procesamiento-de-texto

tengo un codigo cual concadena 2 cadenas de texto, eso funciona al 100%
pero el problema sucede cuando lo repito mucho la funcion

el codigo la funcion para concadenar entero es este:

```
class stg {
private:
const char* data = 0;
char* sumCa(char *txt, char *add) {
    char *res = new char[stg(txt).length() + stg(add).length()];
    char *deb = res;
        do{
            *res = *txt;
            *res++;
        } while (*txt++ != '\0');
    res -= 1;
    do{
        *res = *add;
        *res++;
    } while (*add++ != '\0');
    *res ='\0';
    return deb;
 }


public:
stg(const char* text = ""){
    data = text;
}

stg operator+(const stg &_adder_text)  {
     data = sumCa((char*)data, (char*)_adder_text.data);
}

stg operator+(const char* _adder_text)  {
     data = sumCa((char*)data, (char*)_adder_text);
}
stg operator+(char c)  {
     data = sumCa((char*)data,(char*)c);
}
stg operator+=(const char* _adder_Text) {
     data = sumCa((char*)data, (char*)_adder_Text);
}
stg operator+=(char c) {
     data = sumCa((char*)data, (char*)c);
}

long length() const {
        if (!data){
            return 0;
        }
        long tmp = 0;
        while (data[tmp] != '\0'){
            tmp++;
        }
    return tmp;
}

char operator[](long localidad) const {
    return data[localidad];
}

const char* get(long start, long end){
    if(start < 0 || end <= start || end < 0){
        return "";
    }
    if(end < 1){
        return "";
    }
    char *IO = new char[end - start];
    char *res = IO;
    long long i = start;
    do{
        *IO = data[i];
        *IO++;
        i += 1;
    } while (!(end < i+1));
    return (const char*)res;
}
const char* get() const {
    return data;
}
const char* operator()() const {
    return data;
}
char* operator()() {
    return (char*)data;
}
bool IS(const char* argm, long type = 0){
    if(type == 1){
        if(stg(argm).length() < length()){
            return false;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < stg(argm).length(); i++){
            if(argm[i] !=  data[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(argm == data){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
const char* replace(const char* adder_text, long start, long end){
    stg io = get(0, start);
    io += adder_text;
    io += get(end, length());
    data = io.get();
    return data;
}
};
```

la función cual aplica el uso del código anterior de este es:

```
#define usingForPrint_pt(ucharop_all) cout << ucharop_all;
#define usingForCallSystem(ucharop_all) system(ucharop_all);
class console{
private:
public:
const char* Black = "\e[30m";
const char* Red ="\e[31m";
const char* Green2 ="\e[32m";
const char* Yellow ="\e[33m";
const char* Blue ="\e[34m";
const char* Magenta ="\e[35m";
const char* Cyan ="\e[36m";
const char* White ="\e[37m";

// colores para el fondo de la consola
const char* BG_Black ="\e[40m";
const char* BG_Green ="\e[42m";
const char* BG_Yellow ="\e[43m";
const char* BG_Blue ="\e[44m";
const char* BG_Magenta ="\e[45m";
const char* BG_Cyan ="\e[46m";
const char* BG_White ="\e[47m";

// formatos de letra
const char* F_italics ="\e[3m";
const char* F_transparent ="\e[8m";
const char* F_Normal ="\e[0m";
const char* F_Bold ="\e[1m";
const char* F_Strikethrough ="\e[9m";
const char* F_BlinkingText ="\e[5m";
const char* sysOS = "linux"; 

const char* colors_linux[12][2] = {
      {"reset", "\e[0m"},
      {"bold", "\e[1m"},
      {"underline", "\e[4m"},
      {"invert", "\e[7m"},
      {"black", "\e[30m"},
      {"red", "\e[31m"},
      {"green", "\e[32m"},
      {"yellow", "\e[33m"},
      {"blue", "\e[34m"},
      {"magenta", "\e[35m"},
      {"cyan", "\e[36m"},
      {"white", "\e[37m"}
};
long size_color_linux = 11; 

void _print(stg txt){
    usingForPrint_pt(txt.get())
}
void _print(long txt){
    usingForPrint_pt(txt)
}
void printConsole(stg txt){
    #ifdef sysrun_Mt_Linux
        long n = 0;
        w10(
            if(txt[n] == '\0' || txt[n] == '0'){
                break;
            }else if(txt[n] == '\\'){
                n += 1;
            }else if(txt[n] == '<'){
                n += 1;
                long tmp = n;
                w10(
                    if(txt[n] == '\0' || txt[n] == '0'){
                        n-= 1;
                        break;
                    }else if(txt[n] == '\\'){
                        n += 1;
                    }else if(txt[n] == '>'){
                        if(txt[tmp] == '$'){
                            usingForCallSystem(txt.get(tmp+1,n));
                            txt.replace("", tmp-1, n+1);
                        }else{
                            stg txt_ = txt.get(tmp, n);
                            txt.replace("", tmp-1, n+1);
                            
                            for (size_t i = 0; i < size_color_linux; i++){
                                if(txt_.IS(colors_linux[i][0],1)){
                                    _print(colors_linux[i][1]);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        n = tmp-2;
                        break;
                    }
                )
            }
        )
        _print(txt);
    #else

    #endif
}

}console;
```

la llamada cual supe este error fue básicamente este:

```
console.printConsole("<invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow><invert><blue><cyan><red><yellow> buenas");
```

resultado en la consola es:

> buenasAѱqQ1

la funcion tiene algo raro ya que si llamo a aquella función en corto de texto el resultado es:

```
console.printConsole("<blue> buenas");
```

resultado:

> buenas
> (azul)

visite a valgrind para saber lo que estaba ocurriendo y lo que me marco fue
Invalid write of size 1
Invalid read of size 1
por replace y sumCa

no tengo la idea de que me hagas todo el trabajo solo guiarme en el error que esta ocasionando esto porfavor

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas la clase string? El código no parece aprovechar las clases. ¿Seguro que quieres una clase y no funciones que tomen `char*` como parámetros?

Comment: tengo la necesidad de usar en un char* solamente,  el codigo proporcinado es para un sistema cual no puedo pretenderse a usar string...

Comment: Mira, hay varias cosas que están mal. Como quitarle el const a una referencia o un puntero, o querer convertir de `char` a `char*` de la forma que lo haces. ¿Entonces lo que quieres es hacer tu propia clase similar a string? Dime si [esto](https://ideone.com/EOs41a) es más o menos lo que buscas, aclara la pregunta y te lo explico.

Comment: hola buenas algo asi me pidieron, error solo va cuando en printConsole() va usando aquella funcion demasiadamente, de char a char* te refiere al loop que estoy usando para sumarlo en un char*? no encuentro alguna otra forma para hacerlo, que tendria que aclarar porfa

Comment: Me refiero a `sumCa((char*)data,(char*)c)`. No puedes  convertir de char a char* así. Quizá sea lo que está provocando los caracteres raros. Lo que hace esa línea es convertir el valor de `c` en una dirección de memoria. Lo más adecuado sería pasar la dirección de memoria de la variable: `sumCa(..., &c)`. Me descoloca el `w10` de la clase `console` y los `break` sin ciclos ni `switch`. Los comentarios no están pensados para sostener una conversación larga. Pásate por el [chat]. Quizá puedas discutir el problema con alguien más.

Comment: hola, la función de w10 es while(true){ code__ n+=1;} break esta bien aplicada ya que esta en un ciclo, no  estoy usando sumCa((char*)data,(char*)c) en ningun momento, la función printConsole no la usa nunca, usa  sumCa((char*)data, (char*)_adder_Text);), después de usarse mucha esta sumCa()funcion en una misma cadena  el resultado que me da al usarlo mucho añade letras fantasmas... oka

Comment: necesita de enverdad solucionar este error, string Tambien lo tiene...